# Function parameter description

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've been building a blog on Symfony and noticed something in my code.
This is my query builder and when I set these two `min` and `max` parameters, in this order

```php
public function filterPostsByComment($minComments, $maxComments)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->addSelect("c")
        ->leftJoin("p.comments", "c")
        ->where('SIZE(p.comments) > :minComments')
        ->andWhere('SIZE(p.comments) < :maxComments')
        ->setParameters(
            array(
                'minComments' => $minComments,
                'maxComments' => $maxComments,
            )
        )
        ->orderBy('SIZE(p.comments)', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Here is how my function is shown:

[image]

But when I change the order where the `max` value is first in my query builder, I get the function parameters description like below:

```php
public function filterPostsByComment($maxComments, $minComments)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->addSelect("c")
        ->leftJoin("p.comments", "c")
        ->where('SIZE(p.comments) > :minComments')
        ->andWhere('SIZE(p.comments) < :maxComments')
        ->setParameters(
            array(
                'minComments' => $minComments,
                'maxComments' => $maxComments,
            )
        )
        ->orderBy('SIZE(p.comments)', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

[image]

So, is this a coding syntax or just the IDE bug?

Comment: Have you tried restarting PHPStorm with clean cache? File > Invalidate Caches > [Mark all `Clear ...`] > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Odd indeed. The only possible explanation from me right now: it is natural to expect the smaller param (`min`, `start`, `from`) to be first and `max`/`end` to follow it up) and perhaps the IDE does not show parameter name hints in such specific case (when there are only 2 params and in this order). Anyway: I suggest to create a new plain PHP file, copy the code there, simplify it so it does not use any Symfony code (just make it very basic so it can be tried elsewhere) and see how the IDE will behave in such a case. But yes, it worth doing invaliding caches first.

Comment: I've tried invalidating the IDE cache but perhaps I should try writing a new plain PHP file to see if it still behaves the same

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what's wrong here.

Go to `Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints > [PHP]` and click on `Exclude list...`

There you will find `(min*, max*)` as exclusion. Edit as needed

[image]